# How can I exclude zero length regex matches from my results?

Tags: regex

I did a quick google search and could not find any results. * and ? include zero length matches. How can I exclude them from my results?

For example running a? on "ada" returns a zero length match at 1 and 3. How can I exclude them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very generic question that I'd rather solve on a case-by-case basis; but one option that always works (as long as you have lookahead available - you didn't specify the regexp dialect) is to prepend `(?=.)` to the regexp. `/(?=.)a?/` is functionally equivalent to `/a/`; `/(?=.)a*/` is functionally equivalent to `/a+/`, and to `/aa*/`.

Thus, the examples in your question don't really make sense - you'd never write `/(?=.)a?/` since `/a/` is both syntactically and conceptually simpler. Therefore this is basically an XY-question - it would have been better to ask your real use-case, since it is a moot issue with `/a?/` and `/a*/`.

Comment: I am using java's util classes. I don't know if that helps. I am pretty sure lookahead is available. I think I got it, thank you!

Comment: It is; so `(?=.)` trick should work. But my point is that it it is usually not necessary: if you don't want a zero-match on `/a?/`, then `?` should not be there. It's like putting chicken wings in your chocolate glaze, then trying to figure out how to get rid of the taste of meat in it; you probably shouldn't have put chicken in your chocolate in the first place. (Of course, there's legitimate chocolate chicken recipes; but most people aren't making those, and don't want chicken in their chocolate.) :D

Comment: Yes, understood, sorry, now I feel silly :)

Comment: No worries :D Sorry, I tend to pluck out silly comparisons all the time. No insult intended.